# How to align li menus with dropdowns with classes horizontally

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have this menu structure, but the top level items are not aligning horizontally.
They are the "li" elements with "Lookup Tables" and "MainMenu2" and their dropdowns beneath them.
Currently they appear beneath or a bit over each other.
How must I change my style to do so?

Thanks.

[image]

```css
 #main_nav ul
 {
  background: black;
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
 }

 .dropdown-submenu 
 {
  position: relative;
 }

 .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu 
 {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
 }
```

```html
<nav id="main_nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="position:fixed;top:0px;width:100%;">
  <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: black;color:gainsboro;">
      <ul style="list-style: none; margin: 5px 15px -50px -3px; padding: 2px; left: 0px; width: 20%; position: absolute; background-color: black;">
 <li class="dropdown-menu" style="background-position: inherit; margin: 5px; width: 20%; color: gainsboro; float: left; display: block; position: relative; background-image: inherit; background-attachment: inherit; background-repeat: inherit; background-size: inherit; background-origin: inherit; background-clip: inherit; background-color: black;">
     <a class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" style="color: gainsboro; background-color: black !important;" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
         LookupTables
         <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background: black !important; width: 20%;">
       <li class="dropdown-submenu">
    <a style="color: gainsboro; background-color: black !important;" href="/City/List">
        Cities
    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a style="color: gainsboro; background-color: black !important;" href="/TTT/Edit">
     TTT
      </a>
          </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown-menu show" style="background-position: inherit; margin: 5px; width: 20%; color: gainsboro; float: left; display: block; position: relative; background-image: inherit; background-attachment: inherit; background-repeat: inherit; background-size: inherit; background-origin: inherit; background-clip: inherit; background-color: black;">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="true" style="color: gainsboro; background-color: black !important;" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
   MainMenu2
   <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu show" style="background: black !important; width: 20%;">
   <li class="dropdown-submenu">
       <a style="color: gainsboro; background-color: black !important;" href="/TTT/Edit">
    Vehicles
       </a>
   </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: didn't understand what you are trying to say in the question!!

Comment: How do I get the main level li elements (toplevel menus) to align horizontally. i.e. left to right. They are the ones which have "LookupTables" and "MainMenu2" as their headers or text.

Comment: I have attached an image to show the menus on top of one another instead of side by side.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.
2 changes were required.

I replaced the top 3 lines with this

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-left">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
```

and 
 added

```
display:inline-block
```

to the topline li elements